# basic template not loading in Django

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates

I am really new to Django. Problem is that i can't load my template which consists of two basic html files.
Here is the Location for my template file:

> /home/usman/Django Project/django-black/luckdrum/templates/

Here is my View function:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context
def hello_template(request):
    t=get_template('signup.html')

    return HttpResponse(t)
```

Here is url.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^hello/','blog.views.hello'),
    url(r'^signup.html/','blog.views.hello_template'),

]
```

I have also added the path in my settings.py as TEMPLATE_DIRS.
The server shows an error as Template Doesnot Exist. Please help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your templates in `templates/<app_name>/` or `<app_name>/templates/<app_name>/`. They will be automatically found by Django.

Django will look in the main templates folder `templates/<app_name>/` and after `<app_name>/templates/<app_name>/`.

And then in your view :

```python
from django.shortcuts import render

def hello_template(request):
    return render(request, '<app_name>/signup.html')
```

Here is what your Django project should look like (**as it's recommended by Django to write reusable apps**) :

```bash
mysite/
    manage.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    polls/
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        migrations/
            __init__.py
            0001_initial.py
        models.py
        static/
            polls/
                images/
                    background.gif
                style.css
        templates/
            polls/
                detail.html
                index.html
                results.html
        tests.py
        urls.py
        views.py
    templates/
        admin/
            base_site.html
```

Read django documentation : [Organise templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something) and [How to write reusable apps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/reusable-apps/#your-project-and-your-reusable-app)

Comment: i had moved my templates folder to my app directory i.e.blog and make my view like "t=get_template('<blog>/signup.html') .Its still giving me the same error

Comment: I update my answer, use `render` from `dajngo.shortcut` instead of `get_template`

Comment: @Lois it worked but if i remove an app name <app_names> in vews.py as you mentioned it will work perfectly.

Comment: add related project structure please

Comment: yeah, it works but if the solution that I gave you doesn't works then, it seems that you didn't organize your apps as it's recommend by Django. I updated my answer, read it :)

Comment: thank you so much. :) ! One last question please, if i need to authenticate my app using facebook what framework you work recommend me? :)

Comment: Is it working with my answer? That is an other question then create a new post man :) but take a look at [python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth)