# Templates doesnot exist

Tags: python, django

I just start to learn Django and I stuck with a issue that i Can't solve. Me and My friend want to create a Web site, our project structure is like that `Projet
--home
----migrations
----static
----templates
------home
--------home.html
--Projet
--manage.py
--db.sqlite3`

I get this error :

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
home/home.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.10.1
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
home/home.html
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in get_template, line 25
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.12
Python Path:    
['C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\Jobin.git\\trunk',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\virtualenvwrapper_win-1.2.1-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\virtualenv-15.0.3-py2.7.egg',
 'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\Jobin.git\\trunk',
 'C:\\Windows\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\Python27',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 10 Sep 2016 13:19:12 -0400
```

here is my setting.py

```
 import os

    # Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

    TEMPLATE = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': ['/templates/'],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]
```

I've tried everything on the field 'DIR' , like

```
'DIRS': [BASE_DIR+"/templates", ]
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

My views.py

```
 template_name = 'home/home.html'


    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, self.template_name)
```

still get this error , I don't know what to do anymore anyone has an idea ?

Comment: post your `render` call too

Comment: I added the render call of my views.py of my home app

Comment: What happens if you give `templates/` as `DIR`? or just  give `DIRS` as `[]`?

Comment: I tried but still nothing getting the same error :/

Answer (score 0):

Put your `templates` folder in the same level of `manage.py`

```
--home
----migrations
----static
--Projet
--templates
----home
------home.html
--manage.py
--db.sqlite3
```

Comment: I will try this but I have a question what about if I have more than one App ? Must I put all the Templates in the same Folder ? I saw here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34131385/basic-template-not-loading-in-django)  that there is a Template inside the  App folder  and the author said that it's the recommended way by Django

Comment: in the link they have one template folder with many subfolders, one for each app, that is the recommended way.

Comment: I did what you suggested but it didn't work , still get the same error, I also tried to to change the 'DIRS' field  of the setting to = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates') which when I print it, is the path to the new folder created